# Configuration Import Error

Tags: views, 8, entities, importing-exporting, configuration

I have a drupal8 in local system. I want to import my production environment configurations into my local. So i am running

drush cim -y

I got the following error.

```
Unexpected error during import with operation update for core.entity_view_display.paragraph.card.full: The "linkit" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\
Field\FormatterPluginManager are: address_country_default, address_default, address_plain, address_zone_default, bg_image_formatter, blazy, blazy_media, block_field_label, block_fiel
d, cshs_full_hierarchy, cshs_group_by_root, cshs_flexible_hierarchy, datetime_plain, datetime_custom, datetime_time_ago, datetime_default, daterange_custom, daterange_plain, daterang
e_default, entity_reference_revisions_entity_view, file_default, file_rss_enclosure, file_extension, file_filemime, file_uri, file_url_plain, file_video, file_audio, file_table, file
_size, file_link, geolocation_latlng, geolocation_token, geolocation_map, geolocation_sexagesimal, image, image_url, link, link_separate, media_thumbnail, oembed, metatag_empty_forma
tter, list_key, list_default, paragraph_summary, redirect_source, responsive_image, smart_trim, social_media_default, entity_reference_rss_category, telephone_link, text_default, tex
t_summary_or_trimmed, text_trimmed, item_image_formatter, user_name, author, video_embed_field_colorbox, video_embed_field_video, video_embed_field_thumbnail, video_embed_field_lazyl
oad, viewsreference_formatter, webform_entity_reference_entity_view, webform_entity_reference_link, webform_entity_reference_url, entity_reference_entity_view, timestamp, entity_refe
rence_entity_id, entity_reference_label, boolean, number_decimal, language, basic_string, string, timestamp_ago, uri_link, number_integer, number_unformatted, email_mailto, blazy_fil
e, blazy_video
```

Can anybody help me on how to resolve this?

Comment: `The "linkit" plugin does not exist.` you're missing this. Either you didn't export the config for "linkit" or you're missing the module.

Comment: But that module is already enabled in local

Comment: Maybe run `drush cr` and `drush updb` before `drush cim`. In that order. And maybe put `drush en linkit` in front of that list.